# How can I choose the disturbance model if I know the plant and controller - Transfer functions

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I going to select the disturbance models $C_f$ and $H$. I know my plant $P$ and the controller $C_b$. I also know that the disturbance $d$ is step formed. The noise $v$ is $v = 0$.

[image: System Model]

**Question:**

How should I select $C_f$ and $H$?

I have a theory. If $r = 0$, and the only input to the system is $d$. Then I can write this transfer function:

$$y = PC_fd + Hd$$

And if I want full disturbance rejection, e.g $y = 0$ when $d > 0$.

$$y = (PC_f + H)d = 0$$

That means $PC_f + H = 0$ where $P$ is a known transfer function and $C_f$ and $H$ is unknown transfer functions.

One idea from my self is to set $C_f = \frac{-H}{P}$, but still ... what should $H$ be for transfer function if $d$ is a step-shaped disturbance?

Could I set $H = \frac{1}{s}$ as a disturbance model?

Comment: As an engineering supervisor of mine loved to say, "What are the design requirements?" If you need full disturbance rejection, then why not set $C_f=H=0?$ You must have some other design requirements that force you to pick something else, right? What are those?

Comment: The requirements is that the $y$ should be zero. $H$ cannot be zero because the disturbance $d$ effecting the output $y$.

Comment: I'm missing something high-level here, some context. The reason you gave of "the disturbance $d$ affecting the output $y$" is circular. My point is that choosing $C_f=h=0$ satisfies all the design requirements I see. As this is a trivial case, I'm thinking that, most likely, you have another design requirement forcing you to choose $H\not=0$. What is that design requirement? Is it in the problem statement?

Comment: $y = (PC_f - H)d = 0$ where $d> 0$ and has step shaped form and $H =/= 0$. What is $H$? That's is the problem statement.

Comment: Normally noise is an external element that must be modeled according to its nature. Here $C_f$ and $H$ characterize the noise as if they were modeled by a linear system receiving white noise. $C_f$ and $H$ can not be determined as I please because they are imposed. They are external sources of noise. My $C_b$ controller must be tuned to reduce its effect.

Comment: @Cesareo So there is no idea for dustribance rejection?

Comment: Disturbance rejection should be the controller $C_b$ responsibility only.

Comment: @Cesareo Why does everybody talk about feed forward disturbance rejection then?

Comment: According to this idea then the best solution would be always to choose $C_f = H = 0$ No noise at all to disturb us!

Comment: But $d$ is the disturbance and $v$ is the noise.

Comment: Disturbance can be understood a  structured noise source. A kind of colored noise.

Comment: But in this question, $d$ is shaped as a step input.